# Ionic3 adding a object to an already exisiting firebase object

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I am trying to add a object to an already existing object I have stored on firebase.

I am relatively new to firebase so I am not sure how to go about this but what I have tried is updating that object to add the object I need to it.

location.ts

```
Address = {
    City: '',
    hNo: '',
    rNo: '',
    Blk: ''
}

Function(){
this.firebase.updateUser(this.id, this.Address);
}
```

firebase.ts

```
updateUser(id, v){
  firebase.database().ref('/Users/').child(id).set({Address : v});
}
```

This is an image of my current firebase object with another picture under it with what I am trying to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNmv5.jpg, but what happens instead is that the whole the whole object is overwritten with my newly added object, I am assuming I need to retrieve the whole object and add the object to it and then update it but I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you are using firebase's document `set` command. The `set` is used to create or overwrite a single document.

Rather try to use the `update` command, which should update/add some fields of a document without overwriting the entire document.